# How can I pass two phone numbers to a dialer in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-dialer

This is an iphone example. how can i do this with android. and no i dont want to use a spinner. i want to pass two numbers from my app and have the user select one of the numbers to be dialed.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but AFAIK you will have to render your own UI to allow the user to choose a number, then use that chosen number with `ACTION_DIAL` or `ACTION_CALL`.

Comment: @CommonsWare there is no other way to achieve this with android. or this feature is unique to iPhone.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no other way to achieve this on Android.

Comment: Don't you think that UI is custom build by the app and not the dialer from iOS? If you want to make a call, you send an URL with the number and the system handles it for you, but you have to decide which number to send. I see this behaviour in the contacts app, but it's implemented by the contacts app, no the dialer.  A bottom sheet should work fine if you want to emulate the same behaviour